# Symfony/Twig how to include new javascript functions and avoid duplication?

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, twig

Lets say I have a menu, each menu link loads a `twig template` via ajax into an `html div`

the ajax loaded `twig template page` looks like this:

```
{% extend 'parent' %}

{% block content %}
    <html> ... html code ... </html>
{% endblock %}

{% block js %}
    <script> ... function foo ... <script>
{% endblock %}
```

so each template page has its own javascript functions loaded on demand

now that works fine on first click but if I click a secont time the javascript functions get duplicated and I get error:

```
SyntaxError: Can't create duplicate variable: 'foo'
```

From what I understand the block should erase anything in the parent block right ? Ajax should also replace everything in the div ? but this is not the case apparently...

What is happening please ? How can I avoid duplication ?

before my symfony/twig days I used to just load with `ajax` and php `include` and that was working just fine.

Comment: It seems that you’re injecting the same JS into the page several times. Why are you loading Twig templates with AJAX anyway? Load the JS once, load your structure as JSON, then create the menu structure from the JSON. Much cleaner and less error-prone.

Comment: @lxg thanks for the reply but Im not sure what you mean by "oad your structure as JSON, then create the menu structure from the JSON" ? and how would you you load a page in a specific `div` via `post` without an ajax request ? I do not want to use get in this case.

Comment: I don’t know what exactly you’re trying to achieve here; however, it seems strange to me that you’re firing multiple AJAX requests to build a menu. Why don’t you build it on the server side in the first place? Or in *one* place in the client side.

Comment: @lxg it is not the menu I am building with Ajax; it is content. The menu is already there. Each menu link fires an `ajax` request to load content in a `div`; instead of a traditional `href`. But this loaded content also contains `js scripts` and those get "duplicated"

Comment: I understand what you’re doing, I just think that this is a bad approach (sorry). You’re firing multiple requests to build a menu, which is very bad for performance. AJAX shouldn’t be used for loading structure, but for data. Build the structure on the server and then deliver the whole thing at once!

Comment: @lxg I am sorry but you do not understand what I am saying because as stated in my question and in my previous comment reply I am not building a menu I am indeed loading content or data when I click on a menu item. The menu is never changing. when you say "You’re firing multiple requests to build a menu, which is very bad for performance" this is NOT what I am doing

Comment: Ok, I will assume you have a valid case for doing what you’re doing. I just don’t understand why you can’t deliver the content immediately with the main page. Or, at least, the JS code.

Comment: Can you show us how you append the retrieved data from you ajax calls? It makes no sense that u get the `duplicate` error, as you just have to replace the whole container.

Comment: @DarkBee makes no sense indeed...  I replace with `$('#id').html(myData)`